# What is "Das Mahābhārata Und Seine Theile" about? Is there an English translation of the same?

Tags: mahabharata, translation-request

The German Sanskrit professor [Adolf Holtzmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Holtzmann) has a written a 4-volume book on the Mahābhārata titled *Das Mahābhārata Und Seine Theile*. It's available at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.30331/page/n3).

What is this book and its 4 volumes about? Is there an English translation of the same?